# How to call all the variables defined in Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to practice on constructor functions in JavaScript, here's my code so far-

```
    function officePpl(name,exp,gender,age){
        this.empName = name;
        this.empExp = exp;
        this.empGender = gender;
        this.empAge = age;
    }
    var emp1 = new officePpl("John", 4, "Male", 29);
    var emp2 = new officePpl("Mathew", 4, "Male", 29);
    var emp3 = new officePpl("Smith", 4, "Male", 31);
    showEmp = document.getElementById("empdetails");

    for(var i =0; i<officePpl.length;i++){
        showEmp.innerHTML += this.empName + " " + this.empAge + "<br />";
    }
```

I want to display all the variables created and display them. I'm running a for loop to get the length but the loop is showing undefined undefined only.

Can u suggest how do I output all the variables(emp1,emp2,emp3,emp4) without calling them individually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array to store your employees.
1) When you say `officePpl.length`, it returns length of the function officePpl. This length is nothing but the number of formal parameters the function expects.
In your example it is 4.
Getting `length` property on `employees` is the right way.

2) Later in the for loop, you are referring to `this.empName`. Since for loop is in global scope, `"this"` is bound to window. Since window object doesn't know anything about empName(since it is inside officePpl), it says undefined.

Hope this helps!

```js
function officePpl(name,exp,gender,age){
        this.empName = name;
        this.empExp = exp;
        this.empGender = gender;
        this.empAge = age;
    }
    
    var employees = [];
    
    var emp1 = new officePpl("John", 4, "Male", 29);
    employees.push(emp1);
    var emp2 = new officePpl("Mathew", 4, "Male", 29);
    employees.push(emp2);
    var emp3 = new officePpl("Smith", 4, "Male", 31);
    employees.push(emp3);
    var showEmp = document.getElementById("empdetails");

    for(var i =0; i<employees.length;i++){
        showEmp.innerHTML += employees[i].empName + " " + employees[i].empAge + "<br />";
    }
```

```html
<div id="empdetails"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess an array is what you need, instead of separate variables..

```
function officePpl(name,exp,gender,age){
    this.empName = name;
    this.empExp = exp;
    this.empGender = gender;
    this.empAge = age;
}
var emp = [ new officePpl("John", 4, "Male", 29),
            new officePpl("Mathew", 4, "Male", 29),
            new officePpl("Smith", 4, "Male", 31) ];
showEmp = document.getElementById("empdetails");

for(var i =0; i<emp.length;i++){
    showEmp.innerHTML += emp[i].empName + " " + emp[i].empAge + "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you say `this.empName` , `this`  is not your employee object. `this` keyword refers to the object the function belongs to,  in this case it is `window`.

So writing `this.empName` means `window.empName` which is obvious `undefined`

You have to refer the object you created earlier

```
var ppl = [];
var emp1 = new officePpl("John", 4, "Male", 29);
ppl.push(emp1); // pushing employees to array. Add as many as you want
var emp2 = new officePpl("Mathew", 4, "Male", 29);
var emp3 = new officePpl("Smith", 4, "Male", 31);
showEmp = document.getElementById("empdetails");



for(var i =0; i<ppl.length;i++){
        showEmp.innerHTML += ppl[i].empName + " " + ppl[i].empAge + "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks :) but on doing so console is giving an error "Cannot read property 'empName' of undefined" .

Comment: @tankit88 Yeah you need to added to array and iterate over the array to access each object